# Playwright - How to export the output data to Excel sheet (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, playwright

I tried Exporting the output data to Excel sheet but all the values are storing as a single cell.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Playwright playwright = Playwright.create();

        // select which browser we need to launch and set headless mode
        Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false));
                
        Page page = browser.newPage();
        page.navigate("https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html");
                
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            Locator row = page.locator("table#example tr").nth(i); //represents entire row
            List<String>text = row.allInnerTexts();
                
            text.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
            System.out.println(text.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[   Airi Satou  Accountant  Tokyo   33  $162,700]
[   Angelica Ramos  Chief Executive Officer (CEO)   London  47  $1,200,000]
[   Ashton Cox  Junior Technical Author San Francisco   66  $86,000]
[   Bradley Greer   Software Engineer   London  41  $132,000]
[   Brenden Wagner  Software Engineer   San Francisco   28  $206,850]
[   Brielle Williamson  Integration Specialist  New York    61  $372,000]
[   Bruno Nash  Software Engineer   London  38  $163,500]
[   Caesar Vance    Pre-Sales Support   New York    21  $106,450]
[   Cara Stevens    Sales Assistant New York    46  $145,600]
[   Cedric Kelly    Senior Javascript Developer Edinburgh   22  $433,060]
```

Instead of storing as a full value in a cell (Airi Satou    Accountant  Tokyo   33  $162,700), I need the values to be assigned to each column.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `for` loop for the rows and then another one for columns

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Values for row " + i);
    for (int z = 0; z <= 6; z++) {        
        Locator cell=page.locator("(//tbody)[1]/tr[i]/td[z]"); 
        String text=cell.innerText();
        System.out.println(text.toString());
}
```